Set default config for cloned repositories
How can I set a default config for cloned repositories? Is this possible, or is the config somehow stored in the repository?
Context:

I have set the global config core.filemode = false
I create an empty repository on GitHub. (i.e. I expect no 'forced' or 'non-default' config overrides)

I execute git clone https://<repository>
I inspect ./<repository>/.git/config
Expected
the config file should not contain core.filemode, or have core.filemode = false since this is what I configured globally.
Actual
The clone doesn't follow my global setting:
$ git config --global core.filemode
false
$ git clone https://Me@<Repository>.git
Cloning into '<Repository>'...
Password for 'https://Me@github.com': 
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
$ head -n 3 <Repository>/.git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
$ 

Is there a reason why the clone is overriding my global setting? Is it GitHub? Is there a way to remedy this?

core.filemode is a very special settings.  git-clone and git-init probe the filesystem to see if it handles the executable bit correctly and this variable is automatically set as necessary. See the docs. I don't think there is a way to set it automatically. Even
git -c core.filemode=false init

doesn't work. The only way is to overwrite it manually after clone/init.
